# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Nested Transactions With Multiple Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, transactions

According to the rails documentation nested transactions involving multiple databases should work:

```
User.transaction do
  User.create(:username => 'Kotori')
  User.transaction(:requires_new => true) do
    User.create(:username => 'Nemu')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

How would you go about having a rollback in the nested transaction propagated so that the parent transaction also rolls back?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code does not use multiple databases. Both use the connection from the Client model.

Secondly, you don't specify the DBMS. Different DB drivers have different properties, and not all implement nested transactions. Which DB are you using?

I just did exactly what you want to do, and I am using two postgres DBs. Just throwing ActiveRecord::Rollback will exit the enclosing transaction, but no further exception is thrown. I want to ensure if the nested transaction fails, then the outer one is rolledback.
So, I catch any exceptions in the inner transaction, and then raise a Rollback from there.

Note: Account and User models use different databases, although they both run in the same instance of Postgres. Also, if you leave out the begin rescue clause, then yes, your code will rollback both databases, but you'll be left with an exception unwinding your stack after the outer transaction ends. Finally, I think if there is a problem committing the outer transaction, then the inner transaction will not be rolled back. In my case, that's not a problem. You might want to wrap the DB1 code in a nested transaction, and commit it before starting the DB2 transaction.

```
Account.transaction do
  begin
    acc = Account.do_something_to_accounts
    User.transaction do
      User.do_something_to_users
    end
  rescue => e
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What Jonathan says is correct, but his code example is not quite right.

In order to cancel transactions across both databases you need to detect when the nested transaction is going to be rolled back without the outer one. A standard exception will be uncaught and cause both transactions to rollback. The `ActiveRecord#transaction` block however will silently rescue-and-rollback from a `ActiveRecord::Rollback`, so the solution needs to detect this case in each level of nested transaction (just 1 level in this example) and propagate it.

One solution could look like:

```rb
Account.transaction do
  acc = Account.do_something_to_accounts
  should_rollback = false
  User.transaction do
    begin
      User.do_something_to_users
    rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
      should_rollback = true
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if should_rollback

end
```

An alternative implementation:

```rb
class NestedTransactionRollback < RuntimeError; end

begin
  Account.transaction do
    acc = Account.do_something_to_accounts
    User.transaction do
      begin
        User.do_something_to_users
      rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
        raise NestedTransactionRollback
      end
    end
  end
rescue NestedTransactionRollback
  # Rescue silently...
end
```

EDIT:
You could also get a bit fancy and build a generic solution, something like the following:

```rb
class DistributedDbRollback < RuntimeError; end

def cross_db_transaction(*ar_classes, nested: false, &block)
  return distributed_yield(&block) if ar_classes.empty?

  ar_classes[0].transaction do
    cross_db_transaction(ar_classes[1..-1], nested: true, &block)
  end
rescue DistributedDbRollback
  raise DistributedDbRollback if nested
  # Return nil if we're in the outermost call
end

def distributed_yield(&block)
  yield
rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
  raise DistributedDbRollback
end

# Usage:
# cross_db_transaction(User, Account, Invoice) do
#   ...
# end
```